# How to compile HTML with Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I've a problem with my html code :

`<td id="por">data loads here :{{data}}</td>`

as you can see I am using Angularjs, the problem is when compiling, the 'data' retrieves non compiled HTML, so how can I see my HTML page compiled?

Comment: Do you have any `controller` or `module` code?

Comment: We don't have enough information to know. Post an example with all the html code in one file. Look for exceptions in the browser console.

Comment: @LimAyo Why do you link the $http service? Have you ever followed the basic angularjs tutorial?

Comment: @Pablo thanks man the console helped me , could you please send me links and tutorial that i can follow and understand Angularjs ,thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you `data` contains html code you need to use something like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="data"></div>
```

Just be aware that from AngularJS version 1.2 it has changed to:

```
<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

The more code you provide here, easier will be for us to help you.